# Mensaje de conformacion asp.net mvc 5 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, base-de-datos, asp.net-mvc

No he podido crear un mensaje de confirmación que sirva para que el usuario al hacer si guarde correctamente en la base de datos, y el hacer no no guarde nada en la base de datos, alguna idea de como hacer este tipo de funcionalidad estoy usando el patrón arquitectónico MVC

Comment: Perdón, pero no se entiende nada lo que pusiste. Tenés que ser mas claro y explicar con mayor detalle lo que querés realizar y que problemas e impedimentos encontraste para realizarlo.

Comment: Hola, edita la pregunta e indica en código, el Modelo la Vista y El Controlador.